# How to hook into Objective-C method using Theos Tweak

Tags: ios, hook, tweak, cydia-substrate

I am trying to make to tweak using theos to hook into the application other than SpringBoard. I picked up [DVIA](https://github.com/prateek147/DVIA) application. I want to hook into the following objective-C method *-(BOOL)isLoginValidated* [defined here](https://github.com/prateek147/DVIA/blob/master/DVIA/DamnVulnerableIOSApp/DamnVulnerableIOSApp/RuntimeManipulationDetailsVC.m).

Below, I have mentioned my Tweak inputs:

## Tweak Setup

[image]

## Make File Setup

[image]

## Setup Tweak.x

[image]

I moved the relevant headers inside following directory

> /var/theos/include

After that, I installed my tweaks on using the above files. But whenever I call the respective application/method (DVIA), I don't see any Log in the console.

I am able to hook into the iOS system-level (SpringBoard) method but not able to hook into the any installed application.

Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `DEBUG=1` to enable any kind of logging in your makefile. That should solve it.